# Django: How do I use a string as the keyword in a Q() statement?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm writing a simple search form for a certain model. Let's call the model `Orchard` and give it the attributes `apples`, `oranges`, and `pears`, just for the sake of demonstration.

So, the form does not require all fields to be filled. So you can search on `apples` and `oranges` but not pears. I them need to filter like this:

```
Orchard.objects.filter(apples=request.GET.get('apples'), oranges=request.GET.get('oranges'), pears=request.GET.get('pears'))
```

but if `pears` is empty, no results will ever return.

My first thought was to use `Q` objects, something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

options = {}
options['apples'] = request.GET.get('apples')
options['oranges'] = request.GET.get('oranges')
options['pears'] = request.GET.get('pears')

queries = None

for key in options:
    if options[key] != u'':
        if queries:
            queries &= Q(key=options[key]) # <=== problem here
        else:
            queries = Q(key=options[key])  # <=== same problem here

results = Orchard.objects.filter(queries)
```

The problem comes up in those marked lines. I obviously can't just use "key" as the attribute keyword, because it doesn't take a string, it takes essentially a variable.

So... how do I get around this?

Unless there's a known solution to this problem not involving `Q`. That would be helpful too.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

this is a general issue with using a variable as the key in a keyword arg. the solution is to wrap things in a dict and unpack it:

```
queries &= Q(**{key: options[key]})
```

or in your case

```
for option in options:
    if options[option] is None:
        del(options[option])
# or otherwise only add the ones you actually want to filter on
# then
results = Orchard.objects.filter(**options)
```

Comment: Perfect. This (unpacking dicts) is an element of Python I have never looked into. Thanks very much.

Comment: you commonly see it in subclasses: `def function(*args, **kwargs):`

Comment: Totally save my day!! `Model.objects.filter(Q(**{'name': 'hacker'}))` works but `Model.objects.filter(Q({'name': 'hacker'}))` throws `FieldError: Cannot parse keyword query as dict`

Answer (score 4):

@second's answer is correct, unpack a dictionary with the `**` operator to provide keyword arguments.

However, if you are only using *AND* to combine `Q` objects and not *OR*, then you don't actually need to use `Q` objects in your example. Just build a dictionary of the lookups, then use that as the keyword arguments for `filter`.

```
options = {}
for key in ('apples', 'oranges', 'pears'):
    value = request.GET.get(key)
    if value:
        options[key] = value
results = Orchard.objects.filter(**options)
```